# How to implement Conv2D and maxpooling2d without having a negative dimensions size

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to add Conv2D and Maxpooling to my head model but i can't seem to do so

```
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = (Conv2D(448,(3,3),input_shape=data.shape[1:]))(headModel)
headModel = (MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(7,7)))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(128, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)
```

The Maxpooling2D works perfectly before i add the conv2D but as soon as i do i get the following error

> Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 7 from 5 for '{{node max_pooling2d_6/MaxPool}} = MaxPoolT=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 7, 7, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 7, 7, 1]' with input shapes: [?,5,5,448].
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

Ideally i'd like to have 2 Maxpooling layers and 2 Conv2D layers, so i can have something similar to this
[CNN Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXOrK.png)

Thank you

Comment: You can set `padding='same'` in `Conv2D` to preserve the dimensions of the input feature maps.

Comment: padding='same' does work, thank you

Comment: I have added an answer here. Accept it if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can set `padding='same'` which will add a zero padding to the
> feature maps, thus preserving the dimensions of the feature maps.

The exception ( as stated in the question ) arises when you're trying to perform convolution or max pooling on a feature map, which cannot be reduced further. For instance, the size of your feature map is `( 2 , 2  , 32 )` then you can't perform convolution with kernel size of 3 on it ( with padding=`valid` ).